# Bayes Rule question

Tags: probability

20 percent of blue eyed people have brown hair and thirty percent of non blue eyed people have brown hair. 10 percent of people are blue eyed. A random person has brown hair. What is the probability that person  has blue eyes.

0.2 BE have BH and 
0.3 BE^C have BH
P(BE) = 0.1
P(BE^C) = 0.9
P(BH|BE) = 0.2
P(BH|BE^c) = 0.3
P(BH) = P(BH|BE) + P(BH|BE^c) = 0.2 + 0.3 = 0.5

So P(BE|BH) = P(BH|BE)P(BE)/(P(BH)) = (0.2)(0.1)/(0.5) = 0.4. Is this correct?

Comment: You've asked quite a few questions on this site now. It would be useful for you (and helpful for others) to learn just enough $\LaTeX$ to format the math in your questions nicely. It is (much) easier on the eyes and so doing this will undoubtedly attract more respondents to your questions. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the denominator, how did you get $P(BH) = 0.5$? You have to calculate this given the other numbers $P(BH) = P(BH|BE)P(BE)+P(BH|BE^c)P(BE^C) = 0.2*0.1+0.3*0.9 = 0.29$

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer:
 It looks like you misunderstand [the law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)